# Set mediaquery with jquery

Tags: jquery, mpmediaquery

I wanted to know if this script is OK or not, it should work?
I could also use removeClass

```
    $(window).resize(function() {
  if ($(window).width() <= 890) {   
    $(".vc_custom_1481753917956").css("border", "0px");
   });

};
```

can work? 
can it work? I do not need in CSS but in jquery

[css new img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HHuXf.jpg)

Comment: _it should work?_....Is this your question?

Comment: can it work?............

Answer (score 0):

It will work once you remove the typo regarding the extra braces, however it's always better practice to put responsive styling logic in to a stylesheet where possible:

```css
@media (max-width: 890px) { 
  .vc_custom_1481753917956 {
    border: 0;
  }
}
```

Comment: because there is already a css, with! important, that always wins

Comment: Then don't use `!important`. That's an issue in itself. Make the rule of a higher specificity so that it overrides

Comment: In that case, as I mentioned, your jQuery code will work fine once you remove the extraneous braces.